# Facing problem in matching query from database using python and fetchall()

Tags: python, database, algorithm, database-connection

I have two tables in my database , protein_complex representing a set of proteins
[image]

And here is nonprotein_complex representing a set of non-proteins.
[image]

The proteins and non proteins are referred to by their codes .

The python program  that I have written , aims to take a code from a user , it is supposed to search both the database tables and tell whether the belongs to a protein , non-protein or neither. Here's the code:

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  password="root",
  database="abdb"
)


while True:
    ch = int(input("\n1.Search by code\n2.Search by species\n\nPlease choose an option "))
    if ch==1:
        log =input("Enter the code value for the respective protein\n")
        mycursor = mydb.cursor(buffered=True)
        mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM protein_complex WHERE code_name='%s' ",log)
        mycursor2 = mydb.cursor(buffered=True)
        mycursor2.execute("SELECT * FROM nonprotein_complex WHERE name='%s' ",log)
        
        rows1=mycursor.fetchall()
        rows2=mycursor2.fetchall()
        if rows1 is None:
            if rows2 is None:
                print("Not present")
            else:
                print("Non protein")
        else:
            print("protein")
```

However , in the output , whenever I enter a code , it is only classified into a protein. It never goes to the 'non-protein' or 'none' part. Could you please help me out why this is happening ?

Here's the output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because if and else statements don't work like that. If the first if statement is true, then the second one won't even execute. That means in your example `if rows1 is None:` is not the case then `else: print("protein")` will execute. In your case, the only thing you print out in the else statment is "protein" but nothing else. To actually print both, protein or not, you have to print "protein" and "non protein" in every statement (if you always want to show both results).

Replace your if else statements with the code below, then it should work:

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  password="root",
  database="abdb"
)


while True:
    ch = int(input("\n1.Search by code\n2.Search by species\n\nPlease 
choose an option "))
    if ch==1:
        log =input("Enter the code value for the respective protein\n")
        mycursor = mydb.cursor(buffered=True)
        mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM protein_complex",log)
        mycursor2 = mydb.cursor(buffered=True)
        mycursor2.execute("SELECT * FROM nonprotein_complex",log)

    for row in mycursor:
        if str(log) == str(row):
            print("Protein")
        else:
            print("Not present")
          
    for row in mycursor2:
        if str(log) == str(row):
            print("Nonprotein")
        else:
            print("Not present")
```

Comment: could you please help me out with a set of if else statements  ? As I have been trying out various combinations of those but none of them seem to give the required output.

Comment: Sure, I'll update my answer with a solution soon.

Comment: So, if I understood you correctly, you want to print whether your input is a protein or not?

Comment: yes that is exactly what i want. it could also be none of them

Comment: So I updated my answer now. I hope it works!

Comment: Thank you , will try it out and update you for sure

Comment: I’m sorry but when I used this , it is going back to taking the input from the user again , without giving an output.. It goes back to the line “Search by code/search by species..” without giving an output :(

Comment: Is it possible , there could be a problem using the fetchall() method ? Thank you again so much for helping!

Comment: Yes, remove the fetchall() statements. Let me update my answer again and then you can literally copy paste it :)

Comment: Thank you so much ! Will try this out and let you know

Comment: The code still is not giving any outpur :( .. It is jumping to taking the input again :( Is it possible that connection may not have been established?

Comment: Put "print(row)" right below  "for row in mycursor:" and look if it prints the values from your database. If not, there is a problem with your database connection.

Comment: It is not able to print anything when I try that .. do you have any idea how I could resolve the connection issue ? :(

Comment: It is also not showing any indication that a connection hasn’t been established .. since it did print protein earlier .. we know that it has connected to the database

Comment: I think whether you aren't connected or your SELECT statement is not right. Try to just do "SELECT * FROM protein_complex" and "SELECT * FROM nonprotein_complex" on both mycursor and mycursor2 and tell me if it works now.

Comment: Yes sure just trying that out

Comment: So I tried it out , and it does print all the values in the table , so I guess the connection is there

Comment: Yes and now it should work with these if else statements. Try it out.

Comment: Okay sure will try that out and update you

Comment: It is now printing not present for all values :( Any idea why that would be happening?

Comment: It now displays the error ‘tuple object has no attribute strip’ :(

Comment: I removed the strips. Try it again.

Comment: Or wait, I actually know what the problem is. You get many "Not presents" right? But inbetween there should be a "protein" or "nonprotein" if your input matches the data from the database. So we have to do a identification in the if statements. I'll update you soon.

Comment: yess .. after trying out the code without the strips it goes back to printing 'Not present' for all values.. thank you so much for helping

Comment: No problem but it isn't really done yet right? Because if you want to print "Not present" too then we still have to identify the input value in the database. I mean if you just remove the else statements, your code is done but it is your decision whether you want that too or not.

Comment: After removing the 'not present' , it is not printing whether it is a protein or not :( it just goes back to asking input from the user without printing anything

Comment: Are you sure? It should, at least on my screen. You only removed the else statements right?

Comment: please wait for 2 min , i'll try it out again on my friend's pc.. thank you

Comment: on my friend's pc it displays "not all arguments covered during bytes formatting" :(

Comment: Is the Database connection active?

Comment: yes .. we created a sample database on her pc too with the same table names and data as well as database name too

Comment: Wait, which datatype do the columns have in your database for the proteins and non proteins?

Comment: we've created them of varchar type for now

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: we're using abdb Database.. we're on a google meet call right now sharing our screen.. would you like to join ?

Comment: Yeah I can join for sure

Comment: sure I'll send the link in a minute .. thank you so much

Comment: thank you so much for being with us for three hours straight , and helping us out :)

Comment: You're welcome ^^ And thank you for marking my answer the best :D